# How to insert many rows in a many-to-many table in sql?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, sql-insert

I have a table dbo.dev, a table dbo.req and a third table dbo.dev_has_req.
I created the 547 entries in dbo.dev and created one new entry in dbo.req.

All the new 547 entries in dbo.dev, should have the same req in dbo.req.

That means in the table dbo.dev_has_req, which contains just the 2 columns "idDev" and "idReq", should be 547 the same id of the only new req, for the 547 different dev ids.

how can i insert all of that entries??

Answer (score 3):

Use `insert into - select` :

```
insert into dbo.dev_has_req(idDev,idReq)
select id, 1 /* your request id */
from   dbo.dev
```

OR a proper join synax can also be used like :

```
insert into dbo.dev_has_req(idDev,idReq)
select a.id, b.id
from   dbo.dev a cross join dbo.req b
```

Comment: but in the table dbo.dev, i dont have a Foreign-Key, idReq. 
both tables are just connected through the third table dbo.dev_has-req, which contains 2 columns, idDev and idReq.